# The declaration of the field-symbol is done incorrectly?

Tags: abap

I am having some trouble with activating my program. The idea is that when activating the program I get the below error as shown in the Figure. The error tells me that in line 577 instead of gty_crc_ is expected ty_chck-.

[image]

The code for the upper figure is as shown:

```
FORM cm_show
  USING
    civ_matnr TYPE matnr                  
    civ_charg TYPE charg_d.                
* <--- BOC 

  DATA: lt_crc_list TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zqm_s_crc_list.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lfs_crc_l2> TYPE gty_crc_list.

* ---> EOC 
  CONSTANTS: lc_x TYPE xfeld VALUE 'X'.   

  DATA:
    ls_charg_crc LIKE LINE OF gt_charg_crc,
*    ls_crc_list  LIKE LINE OF gt_crc_list. 
    ls_crc_list  LIKE LINE OF lt_crc_list.
```

The code that I have for the gty_crc_list is as below:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF gty_crc_list,
         pruef          TYPE   zqmkzpruef, 
         qmnum          TYPE   qmnum, 
         qmart          TYPE   zqm_crc_typ, 
         qmtxt          TYPE   zqm_crc_titel, 
         referralqp     TYPE   zreferralqp,
         referralqp_txt TYPE   zreferralqp_txt,
         sttxt          TYPE   sttxt, 
         fecod          TYPE   fecod, 
         fectx          TYPE   qtxtcdgrfe, 
         objnr          TYPE   j_objnr, 
       END OF gty_crc_list,
       gtt_crc_list TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF gty_crc_list.
```

Can anyone tell me if the problem is in the syntax or it has something to do with the naming convention for the tables?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, simplified it to be minimal and reproducible, but I didn't get any error. If you try to make a minimal reproducible example, that will probably help you identify the cause.

Comment: It appears like the TYPES definition is in some scope where it isn't visible to the FORM you have here. But to verify that, we would need a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: is the include where gty_crc_list is defined active?   There is nothing obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's gty_crc_list in an include included before the FORM cm_show include?

**Error:**

```
  Line 10: INCLUDE ZPROGRAM1_F01 <-- FORM cm_show
  Line 11: INCLUDE ZPROGRAM1_TOP <-- GTY_CRC_LIST declaration.
```

**Correct:**

```
  Line 10: INCLUDE ZPROGRAM1_TOP <-- GTY_CRC_LIST declaration.
  Line 11: INCLUDE ZPROGRAM1_F01 <-- FORM cm_show
```